# how to make a editor extened from XMLMultiPageEditorPart readonly

Tags: java-me

I have made an editor extending XMLMultiPageEditorPart
now im opening a xml file in this editor 
i want to make this editor read only ,
IFile file1=file...

i want the xml file which is opened in the editor to be read only.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it.

First: you should define Instance Class of IStorage and IStorageEditorInput,You can refer to [How do I open an editor on something that is not a file?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_on_something_that_is_not_a_file%3F)

Second: Define your own XMLEditor, like this:

```
public class XMLEditor extends XMLMultiPageEditorPart  implements IStorage{}
```

Last: Call editor like this:

```
        File file= new File( path );
        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
        IStorage storage = new FileStorage(file);
        IStorageEditorInput  input = new XMLInput( storage );
        try {
            page.openEditor(input, "Your ID");
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "", path);
        }
```

Note: in the class FileStorage, the function getName() should return the file full path, or you will get errors.

I Hope this can help you, if you have any problem, we can discuss it, use gtalk:vvvv.spring@gmail.com